# how to allow a user to upload a spreadsheet in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parsing, file-upload, spreadsheet

i want a user to have file picker and then choose a spreadsheet which will then be parsed by a controller action.  are there any examples of how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article shows how to add a file upload control on an asp.net mvc page:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx

With this line, you get the file from request:

```
HttpPostedFile hpf = Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFile;
```

After getting it, you can do whatever you want with it.